# Http 302 found error

Tags: magento

When I am making an ajax request to my magento controller, I am getting 302 found. Why is this happening?
My ajax request:

```
var sim_id = $(this).prev().children().first().attr('id');
                            var parent_id = $("#image").attr("data-value");
                            $.get
                            (
                                baseUrl+'/index.php/admin/similar/save/pid/'+parent_id+'/sid/'+sim_id,
                                function(j) {

                                }   
                            );
```

My magneto controller is this:

```
    public function saveAction() {

    Mage::log("inside controller",null,"system.log",true);
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    /*$simImage = Mage::getModel('similar/blogpost');
            $simImage->setProductId($this->getRequest()->getParam('pid'););
            $simImage->setSimimageid($this->getRequest()->getParam('sid'););
            $simImage->save();
   // $blogpost = Mage::getModel('leads/blogpost');

    //$blogpost->load($params['id']);
    $data = $simImage->getData();
    var_dump($data);*/
    return;
}
```

The request is not even hitting the controller. Whats the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form key was not being sent, hence it was not getting inside admin controller